# A-Frame component doesn't work with ES6 Modules?

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I want to call some function (foo) from another javascript file (a.js) when inside my AFRAME component's init function.

in my index.html something like this:

```
<script type="module">
    import {foo} from "a.js";
    AFRAME.registerComponent('registerevents', {
     init: function () {
         foo();
     }
    }
}
```

when I did this, the init function doesn't even get called.

Then I tried something like this:

```
<script type="module" src="a.js"></script>
<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('registerevents', {
     init: function () {
         foo();
     }
    }
}
```

I got a function not defined in this case.

Then I tried in a.js

```
window.foo = foo;
```

in my index.html:

```
<script type="module" src="a.js"></script>
<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('registerevents', {
     init: function () {
         window.foo();
     }
    }
}
```

Then I got a window.foo is not a function error.
What should be the correct way to call a function in the init function? 
Thanks !

Comment: I suspect you might be right about a-frame and modules not working well together I put together this code snippet in case it helps someone else debug https://kindhearted-scarf.glitch.me

Comment: `init` method is not invoked if component is not set to an entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules and A-Frame work fine. The problem is that the [init](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/core/component.html#init) method is not called until a component is set on an entity. For instance, you can set it on `a-scene` as follows:

```
<script type="module">
    import {foo} from './a.mjs';
    AFRAME.registerComponent('registerevents', {
     init: function () {
         foo();
     }
    }); 
    AFRAME.scenes[0].setAttribute('registerevents','');                         
</script>
```

Where a.mjs is:

```
export function foo(){ console.log('Fooing is believing!')}
```

Working example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/little-coral

Comment: That works ! Thank you ! What is the difference between 
```AFRAME.scenes[0].setAttribute('registerevents','');  ```
and 
```<a-scene registerevents>```?
I was using ```<a-scene registerevents>```, init doesn't get called.

Comment: Ah, I know why now. Module scripts are called after ```<a-scene registerevents>```. Everything make sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const AFRAME = window.AFRAME;

const Initialize = () => {
  AFRAME.registerComponent("a-scene", {
    schema: {
      background: { type: "color", default: "#000" },
    },
  });
};
```

and then useEffect:

```
useEffect(()=>{
   Initialize()
})
```